# Why do photoreceptors respond to a wide range of wavelengths?

Tags: optics

I understand that spectral lines for electronic transitions have a *natural line width* and are subject to *Doppler broadening*. But neither suffices to explain why the cone cells in the eye have response curves with FWHM in the tens of nanometers.

Answer (score 2):

The proteins in the light sensitive cells change shape (and so chemical activity) when they absorb a photon - it's not just a simple electron transition in an atom.

Any photon with sufficent energy will be registered - assuming it doesn't have enough energy to destroy the molecule.

See [Visual phototransduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_phototransduction) for details

Comment: I don't think this explains much---why isn't that change in shape associated with a very specific wavelength, corresponding to the difference in energy between the conformations?

Comment: The change in shape is more like the process of absorption in  heating. You don't need a specific wavelength of sunlight to feel warm

Answer (score 2):

There are a ladder of possible electronic states in molecular transitions and in addition those states are broadened by rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom. Thus there are many different ways electrons from the ground state can be promoted to excited state energy levels in a way that conserves both energy and momentum of the photon.

This concept can be visualised by the [Frank-Condon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Condon_principle) diagram. S0 and S1 are electronics energy levels (singlets in this case) and horizontal lines are rotational degrees of freedom. It is not drawn but those lines split due to vibrational degrees of freedom too.

[image: Frank-Condon Diagram from http://photobiology.info/Photochem_files/photochem14.gif]